# How do you output the Zend pagination control outside of the view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I'm creating a wrapper class in the Zend framework to encapsulate some data output and the pagination control.

How do I output this line from the view in the controller:

```
<?= $this->paginationControl($this->oPaginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination-control.phtml')?>
```

Thanks in advance.

...Answered my own question:

```
$this->view->oPaginator = $this->oPaginator;
echo $this->view->paginationControl($this->view->oPaginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination-control.phtml');
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Where is that line now and why does it need to outside of the the View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `view` object in the controller with `$this->view`. So you should be able to echo it like this:

```
echo $this->view->paginationControl($this->view->oPaginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination-control.phtml');
```

But I think there something wrong with your application if you need to echo this in the controller. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for this. It's an ajax call and I've been asked to output the data from the controller rather than from the view.

Comment: Then render the view into the response. `$this->_helper->json(array('body' => $this->view->render('some_ctrl/some_view.phtml')))`.